# Kivy Spinner adds a widget that is not codded

Tags: python, kivy

Can someone explain why below code adds this `Close` `Button` on the bottom of the window you can see on the pic? How to get rid of this?

**CODE**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''

<MenuSpinner@Spinner>  

<Menu@BoxLayout>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MenuSpinner:
        text: 'SPINNER'        
        values: ['1', '2']
    BoxLayout:

Menu:
'''   
sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

[image: IMG]

Comment: I've noticed that when I change `Menu` to any other string it does not add this `Close` `buttton`. I can't find any builtin `Menu` class in kivy doc.

Comment: Do you have a file named `test.kv` nearby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is coming from the `MenuSpinner`, which is already present in Kivy (mostly internal, used by kivy.uix.settings). That class should probably be named differently on the Kivy side, but in any case renaming your version should fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, the name was the cause. Didn't know that `MenuSpinner` is already present.